Prevent routing to another page except when the form page is submitted
I have a custom context UserRegistrationContextProvider that saves the form data and submits it, and my page is a form that I want to detect before the user changes the route to prevent it and show a popup asking to confirm navigation or cancel, I made a custom use hook (useLeavePageConfirm) to handle this logic. The problem I am facing is when the user submits the form, I want to navigate to another page and this triggers the event so the popup appears and I don't want it to appear nor to prevent the routing in this case.
Is there a way to achieve this flow?
Here is the custom context that saves the form data and submit it
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { z } from "zod";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const FormContext = createContext<{
  submitNavigation: boolean;
  setSubmitNavigaton: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}>({} as any);

export const useUserRegistrationContext = () => useContext(FormContext);

export const UserRegistrationContextProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {

  const [submitNavigation, setSubmitNavigaton] = useState(false);
  //rest of the code...

  const router = useRouter();
  const userFormMethods = useForm<FormData>({
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: zodResolver(createValidationSchema()),
  });

  const onUserRegSubmit = userFormMethods.handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    try {
      const regResponse = await axiosInstance.post(/subscribers/",
        { user: data},
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        },
      );
      if (regResponse.status === 201) {
          setSubmitNavigaton(true);
        router.push("/registration/success");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error?.response) setErrorObject(error?.response);
    
    }
  });

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider
      value={{
        ....
        onUserRegSubmit,
        submitNavigation,
        setSubmitNavigaton,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};


and in my page where I have the form I made a formLayout like this and wrapped the page by the context provider.
const FormsLayout: React.FC<IFormsLayout> = ({
  children,
  pageProps,
  ...divProps
}) => {
  const { onUserRegSubmit, onUserEditSubmit, userFormMethods } =
    useUserRegistrationContext();
  const [sideMenu, setSideMenu] =
    useState<{ name: string; children?: string[] }[]>();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="hidden xl:block">
        <FormTitle client={pageProps?.client} form={form} />
      </div>
      <div
        {...divProps}
      >
          <SideMenu/>
        <div>
            <FormProvider {...userFormMethods}>
              <form
                id="reg-form"
                onSubmit={
                  pageProps?.client !== null
                    ? onUserEditSubmit
                    : onUserRegSubmit
                }
              >
                {children}
              </form>
            </FormProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export const getFormsLayout = (_page: ReactElement, pageProps?: any) => {
  return getPrimaryLayout(
    <UserRegistrationContextProvider>
        <FormsLayout pageProps={pageProps}>{_page}</FormsLayout>
    </UserRegistrationContextProvider>,
    pageProps,
  );
};
export default FormsLayout;


and here is my use custom hook useLeavePageConfirm
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useUserRegistrationContext } from "@/context/userRegistrationContext";

export const useLeavePageConfirm = (
  isDirty: boolean,
  setShowPopup: any,
) => {
  const [nextRouterPath, setNextRouterPath] = useState<string>("");

  const router = useRouter();
  const { submitNavigation } = useUserRegistrationContext();
  const onRouteChangeStart = useCallback(
    (nextPath: string) => {
      if (!isDirty || submitNavigation) {
        return;
      }
      setShowPopup(true);
      setNextRouterPath(nextPath);
      router.events.emit("routeChangeError");
      throw "routeChange aborted.";
    },
    [isDirty, submitNavigation],
  );

  const onRejectRouteChange = () => {
    //setNextRouterPath(null);
    setShowPopup(false);
  };

  const onConfirmRouteChange = () => {
    setShowPopup(false);
    removeListener();
    router.push(nextRouterPath);
  };

  const removeListener = () => {
    router.events.off("routeChangeStart", onRouteChangeStart);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", onRouteChangeStart);

    return removeListener;
  }, [onRouteChangeStart, submitNavigation]);

  return { onConfirmRouteChange, onRejectRouteChange };
};


and here is my page
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useUserRegistrationContext } from "@/context/userRegistrationContext";
import { useLeavePageConfirm } from "@/hooks/useLeavePageConfirm";
import LeavePageConfirmation from "@/components/common/popups/LeavePageConfirm";

const UserRegistration= () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const {
    submitNavigation,
    userFormMethods: {
      setValue,
      formState: { isDirty },
    },
  } = useUserRegistrationContext();

  const { onConfirmRouteChange, onRejectRouteChange } = useLeavePageConfirm(
    isDirty,
    setShowPopup,
  );
  let content;
  switch (step) {
    case "step1":
      content = (
        <>
          <UserInfo/>
          <LeavePageConfirmation
            show={showPopup}
            onConfirm={onConfirmRouteChange}
            onCancel={onRejectRouteChange}
            setShowPopup={setShowPopup}
          />
        </>
      );

      break;
    case "step2":
      content = (
        <>
          <PasswordInfo />
          <LeavePageConfirmation
            show={showPopup}
            onConfirm={onConfirmRouteChange}
            onCancel={onRejectRouteChange}
            setShowPopup={setShowPopup}
          />
        </>
      );
      break;
    
  }
  return <>{content}</>;
};

UserRegistration.getLayout = getFormsLayout;
export default UserRegistration;

I expect to prevent the routing unless the user confirms the popup but also to not prevent when the user submits the form correctly to navigate to another page.
I tried to add a submitNavigation state to indicate when the request is accepted and check it in the useLeavePageConfirm hook but due to the asynchronous state, it didn't work correctly each time.
I also thought to pass a function from the use custom hook to remove the listener and pass to the submit function in the context but couldn't make it in this structure.
I am using page router Nextjs.
Thank you!
